# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; MySQL syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a table `favorite_food` in which I have a constraint, a foreign key referencing a `person_id`. I'm using MySQL version 5.7.20 Here is the error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT fk_fav_food_person_id FOREIGN KEY
>   (person_id) REFERENCES person (pers' at line 1

Here is the command:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE favorite_food (  
       person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,  
       food VARCHAR(20),  
       CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY (person_id, food)  
       CONSTRAINT fk_fav_food_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES 
       person (person_id) );
```

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of the first `CONSTRAINT` line.

Comment: When you see an error `near 'XXX ...'`then often something is missing just before `XXX`.